# How to determine agreement between two sets?

Tags: contingency-tables, similarities, cohens-kappa, jaccard-similarity

I have two sets of Ids both drawn from the same background. I'd like to know the appropriate way to compare their similarity. Set A and B are often significantly different in length

eg.

```
Set A = [1, 2, 3]
Set B = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Set Background = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

In my googling efforts, I've discovered the Jaccard Coefficient, Dice Coefficient and kappa score. I've also considered using Fisher Exact or Binomial test as a measure to determine the probability that the overlap occurs as a result of chance. Would one be considered more appropriate than another in this instance?

I don't have a stats background so I've been stumbling around in the dark for a while. Any help would be great.

Comment: Three things are unclear to me: (1) What determines the sample sizes of A and B? (2) Given that your are going to take, say 6 items from the background population for one of the samples, are the numbers 1 through 9 chosen at random without replacement? (Is `2` as likely to be chosen as `9`; is it possible from `2` to be chosen twice?) (3) What do you want to know? Whether choices for A and B are made independently of each other?

Comment: 1) Its a protein ID where the number of IDs are determined by what proteins are identified in a sample (ie protein ID is 1,2,3 etc and sample is A/B), so I guess sample conditions determine size of A and B. Some experiments might be more sensitive (ID more proteins) even though conditions are identical. The background is all the Protein IDs that could be identified. 2) No ID can appear more than once per sample and they are equally likely to be chosen. 3) I think so. Basically how similar are the samples given one can be more sensitive than the other.

Comment: When you say "similarity" do you mean the *distribution* of numbers, or rather their *alignment*? The community here is not naive about *omics, so more detail helps. Maybe you are saying the "background" is a distribution of say G: 0.12, U: 0.24 A: 0.2, C: 0.4 and you want to test if sequence A comes is consistent with "background" or sequence B is consistent with "background". It's totally unclear.

Comment: Ok cool. I have a data set of proteins that I have produced by proteomics of pull-down and a dataset that another study has done the same. I want to know if my finding agrees with the other study. The background is the known proteome of the cell in question. I hope that makes the intention a bit clearer?